# Why did GLBSE close?

Tags: services, finance, glbse

I went to https://glbse.com/ and see it is closed. It was a stock exchange for shares of companies denominated in Bitcoins.

Does anyone know why it closed?

Comment: [Related bitcointalk thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=117201.0)

Comment: See http://bitcoinmagazine.net/interview-with-glbses-nefario/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that Nefario, the person operating GLBSE, decided to go against all bylaws and terms of service and just close GLBSE. That part of the story was explained by [theymos](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=115669.0). It it still unclear, however, why he did it.

Comment: Not sure the protection is warranted ... it seems rushed to me.

Comment: @ripper234 I think that the GLBSE closing down could be an event that would encourage a lot of people to rant and speculate. For not we have 3 answers with reputation 1 - one is just a random comment, one is making claims without giving sources, and one is balanced, but a bit uninformative. I'd rather avoid the mess of the first two types of answers. I guess I'll start a conversation about this topic on meta.

Comment: @ripper234 http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/308/323

Answer (score 5):

At this point in time only one person, Nefario, knows for sure why GLBSE closed.  He was the one who had the power to close it, and he did so, without giving any public explanation.

Everything else is either hearsay or speculation.

Answer (score 1):

Nefario's official reason for closing GLBSE was 1) AML  2) Tax 3) Regulation and he made it clear other shareholder's had no say in the site closing down.

Comment: Citation needed. Where did Nefario state that?

Comment: There is a very long IRC conversation with him chatting to his shareholders about this. I dont have a link but it is out there.